# Multi-Level inheritance not working

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm working on a lab for school and I have it almost completed, but there's one part that I can't get to work. The inheritance works except when I get to Cube. For some reason, it won't calculate the Area or Volume (it just comes up with 0). I'm thinking it's a problem with the way I have the inheritance from Square to Cube. Help would be awesome!

```
package InheritanceTest;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class InheritanceTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "";
        Point point = new Point();

        input = getinput("Set variable X");
        point.setx(input);
        input = getinput("Set variable Y");
        point.sety(input);
        System.out.println("Point, x = " + point.getx() + " y = " + point.gety());

        Square square = new Square();
        input = getinput("Set variable Side Length");
        square.setSideLength(input);
        System.out.println("Square, x = " + point.getx() + " y = " + point.gety()
                + " Area = " + square.getAreaOfSquare() + " Perimeter = "
                + square.getPerimeterOfSquare());

        Cube cube = new Cube();
        input = getinput("Set variable depth");
        cube.setDepth(input);
        System.out.println("cube, x = " + point.getx() + " y = " + point.gety()
                + " Depth = " + cube.getDepth() + " Area = " + cube.getAreaOfCube()
                + " Volume = " + cube.getVolumeOfCube());
    }

    private static String getinput(String string) {
        String x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(string);
        return x;
    }
}
package InheritanceTest;

public class Cube extends Square {

    private int depth;

    Cube() {
        super();
        depth = 0;
    }

    Cube(int x, int y, int sideLength, int d) {
        super(x, y, sideLength);
        this.depth = d;
    }

    public int getAreaOfCube() {
        return (6 * sideLength * sideLength);
    }

    public int getVolumeOfCube() {
        return (sideLength * sideLength * sideLength);
    }

    public String getDepth() {
        return Integer.toString(depth);
    }

    public void setDepth(String i) {
        depth = Integer.parseInt(i);
    }
}
package InheritanceTest;

public class Point {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    Point() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public String getx() {
        return Integer.toString(x);
    }

    public String gety() {
        return Integer.toString(y);
    }

    public void setx(String input) {
        x = Integer.parseInt(input);
    }

    public void sety(String input) {
        y = Integer.parseInt(input);
    }
}
package InheritanceTest;

public class Square extends Point {

    protected int sideLength;

    Square() {
        super();
        sideLength = 0;
    }

    Square(int x, int y, int l) {
        super(x, y);
        this.sideLength = l;
    }

    public int getAreaOfSquare() {
        return sideLength * sideLength;
    }

    public int getPerimeterOfSquare() {
        return sideLength + sideLength;
    }

    public String getSideLength() {
        return Integer.toString(sideLength);
    }

    public void setSideLength(String input) {
        sideLength = Integer.parseInt(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: `sideLength` appears to always be `0` in `Cube`...

Comment: you are confusing sidelength and depth in your code.

Comment: This is a poor use of inheritance. A Cube is not a type of Square, and a Square is not a type of Point. You could potentially use a class such as Spacial to represent things which have a location in space, etc.

Comment: You should also have a single `getArea` and `getVolume` method that gets overriding by each child to change the way that the values are calculated...

Comment: You have some conceptual issues here.  A cube may contain a set of squares and a square may contain a set of points, but it's odd to say that for example a square extends a point.

Comment: The reason why it looks weird is because, to me, the directions are kind of vague. I thought it was asking the user to input certain things, and to give output in case the shape was a square/circle/etc. The only thing the directions say that the program should be asking the user for are x, y, and sideLength. But why wouldn't you ask for depth as well? I agree there shouldn't be points for a square or a circle, but points for those objects could theoretically exist in a plot. The only thing I'm extending in this program is that x=x, y=y, sideLength=sideLength, depth=depth for whatever shape.

Comment: In a cube, the sidelength and the depth should all be same. And you are using the formulas to calculate the area and volume of a cube based on sidelength, which is correct. So what are you using depth for?

Your Square is not picking up your points either. You are just printing out point's co-ordinates, not the square's inherited values. If you do ["Square, x = " + square.getx() + " y = " + square.gety()] then you will see that you have them 0 as well.

To better understand the problem you are facing, can you post the question as is, without any change in the wordings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create cube (new Cube()) you aren't setting the side length (or x and y) for the Square Object it extends.

```
Cube(){
    // This is the constructor called.
    super();
    depth = 0;
}

Cube(int x, int y, int sideLength, int d){
    super(x, y, sideLength);
    this.depth = d;
}
```

You probably want extract the x,y and length values into variables and use "new Cube(x, y, length, depth)"

Something like the following

```
    String x = getinput("Set variable X");
    String y = getinput("Set variable Y");
    String sideLength = getinput("Set variable Side Length");
    String depth getinput("Set variable depth");

    Cube cube = new Cube(x, y, sideLength, depth);
```

Comment: The only thing is that x and y show up as far as inheritance goes. The only thing I'm thinking now is that the method is wrong. Going to try MadProgrammer's suggestion.

Comment: x and y aren't relevant for your bug, but sidelength is used in getVolumeOfCube() and getAreaOfCube(). Its never set, because the super class constructor for Square is only called with empty arguments when you call new Cube().

Comment: I don't understand why it's not working... The inheritance for x and y works. (only reason I'm saying that again is because if there was a problem with the inheritance, then that wouldn't show) Why isn't sideLength showing? I just want to understand for knowledge's sake. How is it empty arguments? And what would I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Ok, lets go step by step. You're creating 3 objects. The first is a Point.  "Point point = new Point()" calls the empty argument constructor. point now has x and y values set to 0. You then call setters on point. The x and y values are set to whatever the user selects. Everything works fine.

Now you create a square, also using the empty argument constructor. This calls the Point constructor with an empty argument. You're setting the side length, similar to before. What you have now is a Square with a side length calculated, but x and y are not defined.

Comment: However, your print statement calls point.getX() and point.getY(), and getArea/getPerimiter functions which only use sidelength, which IS available in the square.

Now you create a cube with an empty argument constructor. It then calls the empty Square constructor, which calls the empty Point constructor. You set the depth using setDepth. You now have an instance of cube with depth set, but sideLength, x and y all set to 0.

The point, the square, and the cube you've created are all separate instances. Anything you do with one of them does not affect the others.

Comment: Ahh, the x and y only show up because I'm calling them from Point. That makes sense. So how would I set them? I can't think of anything right now and my examples that I have from previous classes don't help... Is there a way to salvage this? I know from everyone else's comments that I should have made a generic shape and then had just the one level of inheritance from that.

Comment: Well, its not the best design, but functionally its almost there. All you need to do is use the constructors with arguments in them (See my latest edit in the answer). The constructors with arguments you have set are calling the correct superclass constructors.

eg. in Cube(int x, int y, int sideLength, int d), there is the following "super(x, y, sideLength)". This calls the constructor on the super class (In this case, Square) with the x, y and sideLength arguments. Square, in turn, calls the Point constructor with arguments x and y.

Comment: I just read your edit. Thank you so much!! It works. I should have posted on here earlier... I always try to do things by myself until I freak out at the last minute. Also, rule of thumb for programming: allow yourself at least a night to sleep on things (hours of working on it don't matter if your mind doesn't change). haha Thanks again for explaining it to me!

Comment: @BethanyBrown Please accept the answer (Tick next to the up/down arrows) if this helped :)

Comment: I clicked the arrow, but it says I can't upvote because I need 15 reputation (which I don't have) ;_; Seriously, if I could I would. You've been awesome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at how you are defining getVolumeOfCube(). You are calculating volume with sideLength, but you never set sideLength to any non-zero value.  Change sideLength to depth and you will get the value you are looking for.